# extract href scrapy - crawls but doesn't extract

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using selenium and scrapy to navigate to a table of data and I would like to extract the links/href to a csv file. so far everything i have tried doesn't seem to work and I'm unsure what to try or how to go about getting the links.

here's the important part of the table I am trying to extract the links/href from:

```
<tr class="even">

<td class="paddingColumnValue"> </td>

<td class="nameColumnValue"><a href="/m/app?service=external/sdata_details&sp=12812" class="sdata" title="Click here for additional details.">click</a></td>

<td class="amountColumnValue">$600,000.00</td>

<td class="myListColumnValue"><a href="" onclick="doMyListButton(this.firstChild.getAttribute('src'),this.name);myListHandler(this.name);return false;"  önmouseover="return true" name="12812"><img src="/m/images/add.gif" border="0" title="Click to add this to your list" name="A12812"></a></td>


</tr>
```

the closest I've gotten to actually getting data is with this code...(note table id = search_results)

```
import time
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class ElyseAvenueItem(Item):
    link = Field()

class ElyseAvenueSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "elyse"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = [
'http://www.domain.com']

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='headerRelatedLinks']/ul/li[5]/a")
    el1.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/p[3]/a[1]")
    if el2:
        el2.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    el3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a")
    if el3:
        el3.click()
        time.sleep(20)


        titles = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sdata")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = ElyseAvenueItem()
            item ["link"] = titles.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_results']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a")
            items.append(item)
            return item
```

output to csv:
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x03F16E90

thank you for the help. i can post more of my attempts and their output if that will help. Like I said, what i need is the href and i just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scraping selenium webelement instance instead of it's text. Replace:

```
item ["link"] = titles.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_results']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a")
```

with

```
link = titles.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_results']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a")
item ["link"] = link.get_attribute('href')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's close, but that extracts the stuff inbetween the <a></a> tags...not the href="dfajkfdlajfals" stuff. I need the stuff in the href="".

Comment: this might sound odd, but one problem I seem to have with python is formatting. I've read that tab is not good to use, but to use the spacebar 4x to indent a line. i am using notepad++ and so far, i've yet to be able to type out code on my own with it. i've always had to copy and paste other code, and then modify it to do what i need. do you have any pointers? could this be the reason it's not working? the firefox browser is definitely opening and it's going through the links like it's set to do. the stats simply don't mention any crawling being performed. sorry for such a crap q. :(

Comment: The code I've provided should work if the link really has non-empty href attribute. Use 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: thank you very much. i dunno why but all of a sudden..it "worked". i hate to ask, but is there a reason htmlxpathselector wouldn't work? i've tried it in a thousand combinations and nothing. there are quite a few links on the table and the example i provided only targets one, how would it be possible for me to extract ALL of the hrefs in the table? many many thanks for your help. just to add one point, the tr class "even switches from "even" to "odd" for the table color scheme. i dunno if that would help...